# PyPI package update not upgradable

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have uploaded a module on PyPI and I had recently added version 0.2 of the module on PyPI. 
When I try to upgrade the module using pip, I get an error.

```
~/Desktop pip install musicnow==0.2

Collecting musicnow==0.2
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement musicnow==0.2 (from versions: 0.1)
No matching distribution found for musicnow==0.2
```

Even though on PyPI it shows that I have version 0.2

[image: It shows that I have version 0.2 of my module uploaded on PyPI]

I use this command to upload upgrades of my module : `$ python setup.py register sdist upload`

Comment: Have you tried adding the `--upgrade` or `-U` flag? `pip install -U musicnow==0.2`

Comment: `pip install musicnow -U` worked, but why didn't the original command work?

Comment: I'm guessing that pip will refuse to install a new version of an existing package unless the `--upgrade` flag is explicitly provided. As far as why, the short answer is "that's how they made it," I suppose. :) I'm sure their logic was probably to prevent some accidental scenario. If you didn't have a version of `musicnow` already installed, you wouldn't need `-U` or `--upgrade`, because there would be no destructive change being made.